# Reset State of Slide_to_act widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, mobile, widget

I had a problem when I slide my slide_to_act widget it works correctly and it push me to another page. But when I use nav.pop (when I turn back to old page) my slide_to_act button looks done.
I want to reset it.

```
                  SlideAction(
                    height: 70,
                    sliderRotate: false,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    onSubmit: () {
                      
                      slideAnimated_push(
                          context,
                          ConfirmPage(
                              total: summedPrice.toInt(), slevee: slevee));
                              
                    },
                    innerColor: Colors.white,
                    outerColor: StGreen,
                    elevation: 1,
                    text: 'Slide to Confirm',
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'RaleWay',
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
```

[rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7SOv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know i'm late but i'm also facing this issue today. After looking package files i found a solution.

You can create a **Global key** with **SlideActionState** then assign this key to **SlideAction** widget. Then you will be able to reset the **SlideAction** state.

You can call reset function like this :- **slideActionKey.currentState!.reset();**

here is the example :-

```
//Create a key like this     
final slideActionKey = GlobalKey<SlideActionState>();

SlideAction(
                  key: slideActionKey,
                  onSubmit: () {
                    // you can reset the state like this also
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                      slideActionKey.currentState!.reset();
                    });
                  },
                ))
```

or you can reset it from anywhere you want just use the key.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can reset it after going to the other page.

Comment: how can I reset it ?

Comment: First, give me the steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).